# Deploy python flask project into a website

Tags: python, web, flask, hosting

So I recently finished my python project, grabbing values from an API and put it into my website.

Now I have no clue how I actually start the website (finding a host) and making it accessible to other people, I thought turning to here might find the solution.

I have done a good amount of research, tried "pythonanywhere" and "google app engine" but seem to not really find a solution.

I was hoping to be able to use "hostinger" as a host, as they have a good price and a good host. Contacted them but they said that they couldn't, though I could upload it to a VPS (which they have). Would it work for me to upload my files to this VPS and therefor get it to a website? or should I use another host?

Comment: Hello, I've personnaly used a Raspberry for my own little personal website. Otherwise, people often use Heroku.

Comment: Have you seen https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deployed my first app and used [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python). I'm very happy with it so far and it was fairly straight forward to set up. It does require a basic git understanding but was not hard to learn

Answer (score 0):

A VPS would work, but you'll need to understand basic linux server admin to get things setup properly.

Sounds like you don't have any experience with server admin, so something like App Engine would be great for you. There are a ton of tutorials on the internet for deploying flask to GAE.